# "Recentering" open balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis

Say I have an open ball around the origin with radius r: B(r,0), and I want to transform it so that some point p!= 0 is the center (want to keep radius the same). How can I do this?

Edit: I want p to be invariant under this map.

Comment: Consider the map $F(x) = x+p$ where $p\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $F(B(r,0))=B(r,p)$

Comment: @Yanko.  When p is in the ball, p is not invariant under the map.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Ah now I see his edit... well..